# конвертировать swift в objective c

Tags: swift, конвертация

Может быть, есть какой-то ресурс или программа?
Нужно конвертировать код swift в objective c

Comment: можно кому нибудь денег дать, чтоб сконвертировали

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что оффтопик

Answer (score 2):

Нет таких программ для конвертации кода `swift` в `objective-c`. Одна из причин - в `obj-c` нет многих фишек `swift`, такие как [Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic), [Algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type), [Pattern matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) и другие.

Зато есть конвертер из `obj-c` в `swift`:

1. https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/main
2. http://iswift.org/

<sub>[Источник.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33567230/edit)</sub>

Comment: Надо наоборот))
Не могу сообразить как в Obj-c с photoLibrary передать выбранную картинку - в UIImageView.

Comment: @VladislavHodeev наоборот не получится - нет таких программ)

Comment: оч жаль))Спасибо!

Comment: если вам просто один метод надо переписать, так сделайте вопрос именно про то